# Display some text next to an image regardless of its size

Tags: graphics, boxes

I want to create a command that displays an image and some text next to it. The image should be displayed in its original size and the command will be used with several images that differ in size and aspect ratio. The text should wrap around and it should also be possible to add manual line breaks.

This is what I tried so far:

```
\newcommand{\Bild}[2]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|X}
        \fbox{\includegraphics{#1}}  & 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\TX@col@width}#2\end{minipage}\\
    \end{tabularx}
}

\Bild{bild1.png}{%
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur\\sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
}
```

Unfortunately the text, which should start at the top, is placed below of the image:

[image]

Do you know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `minipage` is doing nothing: an `X` column is a `minipage` already. `X` is a `p` coluumn so the reference point is on the top line of the text the reference point of the image is its bottom edge, so the bottom of the image aligns with the top baseline.
You want the reference point of the image to be near the top so use

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}{\includegraphics{..}}
```